# Bluemix node-red add multiple IBM IoT nodes

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

I understand that we can add IBMIoT nodes to node-red in bluemix and then read the data from the node and do any processing of the data as required by the use case. For this we need to give a device id to the node. Is it possible to create a flow where the device id is dynamic. Let's say I have 10000 sensors / devices. I want to read the data for each of these sensors in a mulitplexed fashion by changing the device id. 
It is impossible to create 10000 device nodes. So, what is the best way to manage this number of sensors / devices?

Answer (score 1):

For the In nodes, set the deviceId to All.

[image]

Then use the `msg.deviceId` property to figure out which deviceId it is.  This can also be used to used with the IBM IoT Out node.  When msg.deviceId is set on a message sent to the Out node, it will **over-ride** what is set in the node itself. 
If it isn't working for you, please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

We can tick All option (device Id) in IBM IoT node option pop up , which helps to connect all Registered devices with different deviceId to Single IBM IoT Node.